# Specifying preprocessor macros for a cocoapod dependency, without forking it

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have an Xcode workspace managed by `Cocoapod` with a few dependencies to external libraries. One of them, [MTDates](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTDates), extends `NSDate` and `NSDateComponents` with either prefixed methods, or non-prefixed if a certain preprocessor macro is defined (which is what I want).

There are a few places where I can put the preprocessor macro definition in order to have the compiled library provide the non-prefixed methods, but all seem to be reset as soon as I ask `Cocoapod` to update the project, which leads me to think that these configs are driven by the pod spec. These include :

- The pod's target build settings
- The pod's private `.xcconfig` file in Cocoapod's *Targets Support Files*

Changing the pod's spec would require to manage my own version of the library, whereby losing the ability for `cocoapods` to update it when a new version comes around. So my question is: is there a way to specify a preprocessor macro for a `cocoapod` dependency, without forking the pod and changing the pod's spec itself?

**Edit**:

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/833) about this, that seem to be just around the corner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This functionality is now available.  Here is an example of what you could put at the bottom of your Podfile to add a macro based on a specific configuration.

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "Pods-TweaksBuildConfigurationsDemo-Tweaks"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        if config.name == 'QA'
          config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'FB_TWEAK_ENABLED=1']
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Using cocoapods version 1.0.0.beta.3 I have to use installer_representation.pods_project rather than installer_representation.project

Comment: So you need to add 10 lines of code to define a macro? That's terrible.

Comment: This **overwrites any existing** dependency setting instead of "adding".

Answer (score 3):

as you mentioned 'The pod's private .xcconfig file in Cocoapod's Targets Support Files', i do this resolved my problem.

```
s.xcconfig = {'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => '$(inherited) COCOAPODS=1 IOS=1' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Cocoapods documentation, I don't think this is possible just yet, I think what you can do is to copy the pod spec - make the changes you want (e.g `s.prefix_header_contents = #define symbolToDefine`) and then add it to your local specs with a different name, and use that in your pod file. When a new version comes out unfortunately, you'd have to go in and change the tag number (and other stuff depending on the changes).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that answers my question. I will go ahead and file an issue to see if such functionality can make its way to master.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Swift preprocessor flags and podspecs:

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
  'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS' => '$(inherited) -D DEFINE_ME'
}
```